# Python - Search for a match for a word in a list of words in a string

Tags: python, string-matching

I have a string like this:

```
text = "The best language in the word is $python at now"
```

and a list of words to search:

```
keywords = ["PYTHON","PHP","JAVA","COBOL","CPP","VB","HTML"]
```

How to have "PYTHON" as result?

Comment: how did $python got matched with PYTHON?

Comment: @SreeramTP - Clearly even binary computing recognises that python is the best language in the word

Comment: @SreeramTP because the word could be preceded by a symbol

Comment: you could use this: `res = [elt for elt in keywords if elt.lower() in text.lower()]; print(res)` where `res` will be list of all matching words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python you can easily check if a string contains another by using the `in` operator.

Just check the string for each keyword, and remember to make the case the same.

You can use one line

```py
[print(x) for x in keywords if x in text.upper()]
```

or multiple

```py
for x in keywords:
    if x in text.upper():
        print(x)
```

In your case the following example will output `PYTHON`:

```py
text     = "The best language in the word is $python at now"
keywords = ["PYTHON","PHP","JAVA","COBOL","CPP","VB","HTML"] 

[print(x) for x in keywords if x in text.upper()] #PYTHON
```

Have a nice day.

**edit**

As Malo indicated, i might be better style to pass the output to a variable and then print it after.

```py
text     = "The best language in the word is $python at now"
keywords = ["PYTHON","PHP","JAVA","COBOL","CPP","VB","HTML"] 

matches  = [x for x in keywords if x in text.upper()]

for x in matches: print(x) # PYTHON
```

Comment: `print(x)` returns `None`. try executing this: `lst = [print(x) for x in keywords if x in text.upper()]; print(lst)`

Comment: [x for x in keywords if x in text.upper()]  returns a list of matching words directly.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, but you have to get rid of the `$` before `python`:

```
text = "The best language in the word is python at now"

keywords = ["PYTHON","PHP","JAVA","COBOL","CPP","VB","HTML"]

upper_text = text.upper()

ar_text = upper_text.split()

for word in keywords:
    if word in ar_text:
        print(word)
```

Comment: If you didn't split up the `upper_text` you wouldn't need to remove anything from the string `if word in upper_text` is enough

Comment: Good. Just ar_text does not need to be splitted.

Answer (score 0):

This will use find to check if any of the list items are in the string (case-insensitive, since this is what you're asking):

```
results = []
for keyword in keywords:
    if text.lower().find(keyword.lower()) != -1:
        results.append(keyword)

print(results)
```